# Removing a sublist from a list that meets a certain condition

Tags: python

I create all three-element permutations without mirroring, using `itertools.product()`:

```
import itertools

list_1 = [list(i) for i in itertools.product(tuple(range(4)), repeat=3) if tuple(reversed(i)) >= tuple(i)]
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 3], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 1], [0, 2, 2], [0, 2, 3], [0, 3, 0], [0, 3, 1], [0, 3, 2], [0, 3, 3], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 3], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 1], [1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 3], [2, 0, 2], [2, 0, 3], [2, 1, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 2], [2, 3, 3], [3, 0, 3], [3, 1, 3], [3, 2, 3], [3, 3, 3]]
```

How do I delete these sublisters from the list `list_1`, which have the same number of corresponding values and then leave only one of them?

For example, in sublists `[1,1,2], [1,2,1]` the number of given values is the same in all, that is, in each sub-list there are two `1` and one `2`, that's why I consider the sublisters to be the same and that's why I want to leave only the first one, namely  `[1,1,2]`. How can this be done?

I was thinking about counting the number of corresponding values in each sub-list and creating a list with the occurring feature regarding the amount of given values, and then checking each element from the list list_1 in the loop or the element with the given feature has not occurred before. But it seems to me to be very complicated.

Comment: Use the `Counter` structure; if two items have the same `count` dict, then remove the duplicate.  Is that enough of a hint?

Comment: Rory Daulton gave the simplest solution :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than using `product` from the `itertools` module, use [combinations_with_replacement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement). That does what you want in one line without any massaging afterward:

```
list1 = [list(i) for i in combinations_with_replacement(range(4),3)]
```

The result of `print(list1)` after that is

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 3], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 2], [0, 2, 3], [0, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]]
```

Note that your conversion of the `range` object to a tuple is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort each sublist and then extract unique sublists out as follows.

```
list_2 = map(sorted, list_1)
list_u = []
[list_u.append(x) for x in list_2 if x not in list_u]
```

Output:

```
list_u = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 3], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 2], [0, 2, 3], [0, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]]
```

Now, there are more efficient options than sorting each sublist, but I will leave that upto you.

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick:

```
import itertools

def uniqifyList(list):
    indexToReturn = []
    sortedUniqueItems = []

    for idx, value in enumerate(list):
        # check if exists in unique_list or not
        value.sort()
        if value not in sortedUniqueItems:
            sortedUniqueItems.append(value)
            indexToReturn.append(idx)

    return [list[i] for i in indexToReturn]

list1 = [list(i) for i in itertools.product(tuple(range(4)), repeat=3) if tuple(reversed(i)) >= tuple(i)]
print(list1)

list2 = uniqifyList(list1)
print(list2)
```

Which outputs:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 3], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 2], [0, 2, 3], [0, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 3], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]]
```